# How to redirect Request.Content stream

Tags: c#, stream, task-parallel-library

I trying to copy an incoming HTTP stream into another stream and use that instead.

When I use `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` directly, everything works fine.

The problem that I am facing is how to "channel" the original stream thru another one.
I wrote the flowing method, but the problem is that it either blocks until all the stream data has arrived (when I use Wait()), or it returns immediately and exists without capturing any data.

```
 private  Task<Stream> GetAudioStream(RecordingSession recordingSession)
    {

        Task<Stream> task = Task<Stream>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result.CopyToAsync(recordingSession.AudioStream).Wait();
            return recordingSession.AudioStream;
        });

        return task;
    }
```

Comment: You're in the habit of starting async operations, then waiting for them. That makes no sense.

Comment: @usr Sure, but if I don't wait, the code exits immediately and I get no data. This is the actual question.

Comment: Then, I'm unclear what you want. You have the two choices: Return immediately, return when done. What else do you want?

Comment: Instead of using async, then waiting, just use the synchronous methods. At the moment you are getting the worst of both sync and async with this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you tackle the problem from the wrong side. `CopyToAsync` gives you a *complete* copy of the stream, the `Task` returned by `CopyToAsync` is completed when all data has been copied.

If you don't need the whole *complete* copy of the stream, or don't want to wait for *all data*, then copy it manually yourself and process each chunk:

```
static async Task<Stream> CopyAndProcessAsync(RecordingSession recordingSession, CancellationToken token)
{
    var srcStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    var dstStream = recordingSession.AudioStream;

    var buffer = new byte[4096];  
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = await srcStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
    {
        await dstStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // do whatever you want with the chunk
        PlaybackChunk(buffer);
    }

    return dstStream;
}
```

Do this wherever you'd otherwise be consuming the result of your `GetAudioStream`. It well may turn out that you don't need a copy at all, when you've processed each chunk.

Comment: What I needed to do, is to use recordingSession.AudioStream while it is being written, but now I understand that it is impossible to read from a stream that is being written.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
private async Task<Stream> GetAudioStream(RecordingSession recordingSession)
{
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await result.CopyToAsync(recordingSession.AudioStream);
    return recordingSession.AudioStream;
}
```

async methods return Tasks. Very rarely should a non-async method return a Task.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve the problem. It either blocks until all the data is streamed, or it returns immediately if I remove the second await.

Comment: Right, that's because your calling method should await the completion of the call to GetAudioStream().

Comment: I am awaiting on GetAudioStream(), but it still returns immediately.